# Positive definiteness of a correlation matrix

Tags: matrices, correlation, positive-definite

With $n$ natural numbers 1, 2, ..., $n$, there are $N=n(n-1)/2$ unique pairs that are the 2-D indices for random variables $z_{ij}$ ($1 \le i < j \le n$). I have the correlation matrix $A$ of $z_{ij}$ that is defined as follows:

$cor(z_{i_1 j_1}, z_{i_2 j_2})=1$, if $i_1=i_2, j_1=j_2$;

$cor(z_{i_1 j_1}, z_{i_2 j_2})=\rho$,  if $\{i_1,j_1\}∩\{i_2,j_2\}$ has cardinality 1;

$cor(z_{i_1 j_1}, z_{i_2 j_2})=0$, if $i_1\neq i_2, j_1\neq j_2$.

For example, with $n=5$, the correlation matrix $A$ for the $N=n(n-1)/2=10$ $z$-variables is of the following structure,

${\begin{array}{c}
z_{12} \\
z_{13} \\
z_{14} \\
z_{15} \\
z_{23} \\
z_{24} \\
z_{25} \\
z_{34} \\
z_{35} \\
z_{45} \\
\end{array}}
\left[{\begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
1 & \rho & \rho & \rho & \rho & \rho & \rho & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\rho & 1 & \rho & \rho & \rho & 0 & 0 & \rho & \rho & 0 \\
\rho & \rho & 1 & \rho & 0 & \rho & 0 & \rho & 0 & \rho \\
\rho & \rho & \rho & 1 & 0 & 0 & \rho & 0 & \rho & \rho \\
\rho & \rho & 0 & 0 & 1 & \rho & \rho & \rho & \rho & 0 \\
\rho & 0 & \rho & 0 & \rho & 1 & \rho & \rho & 0 & \rho \\
\rho & 0 & 0 & \rho & \rho & \rho   & 1 & 0 & \rho & \rho \\
0 & \rho & \rho & 0 & \rho & \rho & 0 & 1 & \rho & \rho \\
0 & \rho & 0 & \rho & \rho & 0 & \rho & \rho & 1 & \rho \\
0 & 0 & \rho  & \rho  & 0 & \rho & \rho & \rho & \rho & 1\\
\end{array}}\right].$

I have two questions:

1) Is there a special name for this type of matrix?

2) For the few $n$ values I've played with, it seems that $A$ is non-negative definitive if $ 0 \le \rho \le 0.5$. Is there a way to prove that $A$ is not positive definitive when $0.5 < \rho \le  1$?

Comment: @A.S.  Certainly not!  Nonsingular does not imply positive definite.

Comment: @A.S. How do you know $A_n$ is positive semidefinite?

Comment: But the point is that it is **not** a covariance matrix if $\rho > 1/2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $z_{13}, z_{14}, z_{23}, z_{24}$.  Their covariance matrix is
$$ A = \pmatrix{1 & \rho & \rho & 0\cr \rho & 1 & 0 & \rho\cr \rho & 0 & 1 & \rho\cr 0 & \rho & \rho & 1\cr}$$
Its characteristic polynomial factors as 
$$ (\lambda - 1)^2 (\lambda + 2 \rho - 1)(\lambda - 1 - 2 \rho)$$
so for this to be positive semidefinite we need $-1/2 \le \rho \le 1/2$.
For any $n \ge 4$, this is a principal submatrix of $A$, so $-1/2 \le \rho \le 1/2$ is a necessary condition for $A$ to be positive semidefinite.

On the other hand, for $n=3$ there are only three variables
$z_{12},z_{13},z_{23}$, and $$A = \pmatrix{1 & \rho & \rho\cr \rho & 1 & \rho \cr \rho & \rho & 1\cr}\ \text{or}\  \pmatrix{1 & \rho & 0\cr \rho & 1 & \rho \cr 0 & \rho & 1\cr}$$
(depending on the interpretation, as noted in the comments).
The first is positive semidefinite for $ -1/2 \le \rho \le 1$, the second for $-1/\sqrt{2} \le \rho \le 1/\sqrt{2}$.

I can also show that $A$ **is** positive semidefinite for $0 \le \rho \le 1/2$ (in the interpretation where the covariance is $\rho$ if $\{i_1,j_1\} \cap \{i_2,j_2\}$ has cardinality $1$).  To do this it's enough to find a probability model for $\rho = 1/2$ where the variables $z_{ij}$ have these covariances, and then use the fact that the positive semidefinite matrices form a convex set.
Such a model can be obtained as follows: let $B_i$ be iid random variables taking values $\pm 1$, each with probability $1/2$, and let 
$Z_{ij} = (B_i + B_j)/\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @Robert Israel Thanks a lot for the wonderful answer! I've updated my original question to clarify the ambiguity, so you may want to modify your answer accordingly. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks again for the beautiful proof! It remains moot to me whether $A$ is positive semidefinite for $-1/2 \le \rho < 0$. I'm not so sure if it makes sense to have negative $\rho$ values, but, for completeness, it would be nice to sort out this last part.

Comment: With a few matrices I've tried, it seems that $-0.5 \le \rho < 0$ is not sufficient to guarantee the positive semi-definiteness of $A$. How to rigorously prove this part? So $0 \le \rho \le 0.5$ is a sufficient and necessary condition.

Comment: If $0 \ge \rho \ge -1/(2n-4)$, the matrix will be diagonally dominant and therefore positive semidefinite.

Comment: On the other hand, the vector $\bf 1$ of all $1$'s is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $1 + (2n-4) \rho$, so $A$ is not positive semidefinite if $\rho < -1/(2n-4)$.  Thus the full condition is $-1/(2n-4) \le \rho \le 1/2$.